# TIMESTAMP default value error

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1067

I exported SQL script with workbench to phpMyAdmin and I get an error because of TIMESTAMP default value.

Here's a piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`is_users` (
  `count` INT(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `active` ENUM('1', '0') NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `id` VARCHAR(36) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
  `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

And I get an error :

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'created_at'

To avoid an error, the default date should be for example 1970-01-01 01:01:01, it means that there cannot be zeros. 
How could I fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1);
```

If your system runs in another timezone than UTC then you will not get '1970-01-01 00:00:01' as result. For example, my system is running in CET which results in '1970-01-01 01:00:01'. So this result should work as a default value for your table.

Answer (score 0):

00:00:01 is valid for a time.

TIMESTAMP DEFAULT processing changed at 5.6.5.  What version are you using?  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

I do not get an error in 5.6.12.

Solution:  Upgrade to 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is enough to delete this part of code:

```
 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`
```

Answer (score 0):

On 5.7, you want to disable the `TRADITIONAL` in `sql_mode` in order to to be able to support `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` in datetime and timestamp, or 0s in time as you need. 
For instance, by default on 5.7.10, [SQL MODES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) are:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You would do this by either setting `sql_mode` in your `my.cf` file or with command the line as follow:

```
SET sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

You may want to keep some other modes on, and you should have a look on the documentation linked above. This is quite tricky as some modes are dependent on others.